# Testing the error_handlers in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I added the following error handler in the app engine app.yaml file:

```
error_handlers:
- file: default_error.html
```

Then I planned to test it with a forced DeadlineExceededError

So I have a request handler:

```
class Timeout(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    count=100
    if self.request.get('count'):
        count=int(self.request.get('count'))
    time.sleep(count)
```

I call http://20-social.race-timing-failsafe.appspot.com/timeout?count=100 and I would expect my default_error.html file be displayed.

Instead I see:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

Could this be caused by the artificial deadline exceeded via time.sleep.  It seems to work for the syntax error case and "real" deadline exceeded messages (e.g., timeout when writing to datastore) and hopefully for quota exceeded.

What causes the `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` message?  And where is it coming from?  I searched the google appengine sdk python code and did not find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That error message isn't the raw Google one, so it looks like something else in your stack is trapping the exception and giving that response.

That default error handler is only served if an exception is not caught anywhere in your application.

e.g stick a raise StringError before you start any webapp stuff and see what happens ;-)

Comment: Hi Tim, You are correct. It is a message from the web framework.  See http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html.  From the documentation: `error_body`
`The error response body. This should be an HTTP response body string. It defaults to the plain text, “A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.”`